# Powershell - Remove all network profiles excluding one

Tags: powershell, networking

I am trying to remove all saved wifi profiles excluding one.

I have the below and it works but I don't want to remove / forget one of the wifi SSID

$NetProfiles = (netsh.exe wlan show profiles)
$NetProfiles | netsh WLAN delete profile*

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using the module : [Networking](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/xNetworking/5.7.0.0)

You have two possibilities, firstly get your profil connected and then remove all the other profil save excluding the connected profile :

```
$connectedProfile = (Get-NetworksConnection).Name
$profiles = Get-NetworksProfile
foreach ($profile in $profiles) {
    if ($profile.Name -ne $connectedProfile) {
        Remove-NetworksProfile -Name $profile.Name
    }
}
```

Or, delete all except the one you want by exclude the one needed :

```
$profiles = Get-NetworksProfile
foreach ($profile in $profiles) {
    if ($profile.Name -ne "myprofil") {
        Remove-NetworksProfile -Name $profile.Name
    }
}
```

you can change "myprofile" to the name you want to exclude or even a list of names.

Comment: `Get-NetworksConnection` / `Remove-NetworksProfile` / `Get-NetworksProfile` are not default cmdlets - what module are they from? Why not use `Get-NetConnectionProfile`?

Comment: I'm using the module Networking (added on the answer). I guess it could be done with Get-NetConnectionProfile too

Comment: Hi Both, 
Thank you for your response and input. 
Can this be achieved without having to install & import a module?

Also, when using Get-NetConnectionProfile it only lists active connections. Can I somehow list all connections, active and historical?